# Display category title on category page, Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

Wondering how to display the name of the category on actual category pages in Magento 2?  I can get the image and everything else to show up, just no spot to have the category name in an H1 or something?

Comment: The category title displayed already with default magento2.1, then can you please  explain in detail what you are going to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Category page title **H1 tag** in side this path `vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\title.phtml`.

Comment: What if you don't want the h1 tag, just the actual name of the category?

Answer (score 0):

Page Title HTML **H1 TAG** Can be edited at Vendor/Magento/module-theme/view/frontend/html/title.phtml
You can override this within your theme / Module
If you just like to move the title Vendor/Magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/lauout/catalog_category_view.xml
override this to your theme/Module and 
Add: